# Implementation is not working

Tags: java, inheritance, implementation, parent-child

I have 4 classes. One is a driver class, one and interface and two child classes. This is the Interface class:

```
public interface Speaker {
    public void speak();
    public void announce(String announcement);
}
```

This is the driver class:

```
public abstract class SpeakerDriver implements Speaker {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Speaker ref;
        Politician poli = new Politician("George Bush");
        Lecturer lect = new Lecturer("Professor Cross");
        Pastor past = new Pastor ("P.M. Smith");

        ref = poli;
        ref = lect;
        ref = past;

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(lect);
        System.out.println(past);   
    }
}
```

and these are the two child classes:

```
public class Pastor implements Speaker {
    protected String announcement;

    public Pastor (String name) {       
    }

    @Override
    public void speak() {   
    }

    @Override
    public void announce(String announc) {
        System.out.println("I am the pastor at CCBC."); 
    }
}

public class Lecturer implements Speaker {
    protected String announcement;

    public Lecturer(String name) {
    }

    @Override
    public void speak() {
    }

    @Override
    public void announce(String announcement) {     
        System.out.println("I am the lecturer at CCBC");    
    }
}
```

My question is, what is wrong with my implementation that is making the output look like this:

```
Lecturer@a90653
Pastor@de6ced
```

When they should contain the text that is in the println.

Comment: It's a bit weird to see a parameter being passed to `announce` and then dropped on the floor.  I understand it's an interface requirement, but that should force you to use the parameter in some way...  Also, it's a bit weirder that `announce` doesn't return `String`.  Just sayin'.

Comment: You don't give the speaker a name, 'cause your not saving their values in the constructor. This way you can override `toString()`.

Answer (score 5):

You are printing the object with this statement:

```
System.out.println(lect);
```

You probably meant to call a function on the object:

```
lect.announce();
```

Also note that your driver class does not actually need to implement the 'Speaker' interface, and the of the following statements, the first two effectively accomplish nothing:

```
ref = poli;
ref = lect;
ref = past;
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to implement a toString() method in each of the subclasses.

```
public String toString() {
    return this.name;
}
```

something like that. print() calls this method to return a string.

EDIT: ignore, didn't read the end bit.

Comment: Indeed. Too much python recently. Thank you

Comment: What exactly is this.name? I changed it to return announcement after adding setter and getter methods.

Comment: You should use the solution above, but for `this.name`, you need a field name for the subclasses and the constructor need to set `this.name = name`, as you already pass in name.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this you need to override the toString() method in each of your classes, what this output is the address and type of the object because Java does not know how to convert it to a string otherwise. It seems like you may have meant to call {object}.announce() rather than trying to print the object.